# SQL to Merge Date fields

Tags: sql, date, merge, group-by

Can anyone help? I have a table which has a datetime field and duration.. what I need is to merge the records that happened on one day... As below, My first column shows the date, the second the amount of hours available and then the minutes... As you can see there is a morning and afternoon, what I need is to select just one record for each day and then total duration, so it shows for 10th July 2004 just one record and then a duration count of 7 hours 30 minutes.

```
2004-10-07 09:00:00.000 4   0
2004-10-07 14:00:00.000 3   30
2004-10-08 09:00:00.000 4   0
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you want to convert the date time to a date and group by that.  Then you want to sum the hours and minutes.  It is easy to sum them as minutes `60*h + m`.  However, to split this back into hours and minutes requires a bit of arithmetic.

Here is one method:

```
select cast(dt as date),
       cast(sum(h * 60 + m)/60 as int) as hours,
       sum(h * 60 + m) - 60 * cast(sum(h * 60 + m)/60 as int) as minutes
from t
group by cast(dt as date);
```

Unfortunately, the specific operations for converting to a date depend on the database.  Also, the syntax for the "modulus" operation may differ among databases, so this takes the safer route of doing the calculation directly.

Comment: no need for the complex minutes calculation as most DBMSes support a MODULO operator: sum(h * 60 + m)/60 -> hours and sum(h * 60 + m) MOD 60 -> minutes

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Or `sum(m) % 60`.  Or, `mod(sum(m), 60)`.  That's one reason I asked for the database.  (For the resulting minutes using mod, you don't need the hours in the calculation).)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using some database which supports the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` commands, try this:

This works fine for sqlite3:

```
SELECT date(date), (sum(hours)*60+sum(minutes))/60, sum(minutes)%60
FROM dates
GROUP BY date(date)
```

This is the answer to the follow-up question in the comments:

```
SELECT
date(free.date),
(SUM(hours)*60+SUM(free.minutes))-
(SELECT (SUM(hours)*60+SUM(used.minutes))
    FROM used
    WHERE date(used.date)=date(free.date))
FROM free
WHERE date(free.date) IN (SELECT DISTINCT date(used.date) FROM used)
GROUP BY date(free.date);
```

Comment: Thanks... I what I was after... I do have one more question, in another table which has time and date field too, but in the time part it has for example 10 minutes, my first shows the opening times and then second table allows times to be added to that, I have total duration now but somehow need to link the two to work out duration free if that makes sense?

Comment: As long as the two tables are connected via IDs, this works just as well. Use the select statement from above and add after the `FROM dates` another part, which joins your second table. The `GROUP BY` works even on these joined tables. Read up on `inner join` if you have any more questions. :)

Comment: Thanks, I joined the tables ok - it was more a formula to work out what time is free... for example the first table has 7 hours free... the second table has say 30 records for the same day within that 7 hours, each one say 5 minutes... so 150 minutes in total... its how to add up the used time and then minus that from the free duration I already have... Sorry if it sounds dumb, I know in my head I know what I mean :)

Comment: It took me a minute but I think I know what you want. For testing, I created two tables: `free` which is the table you mentioned in the original question. `used` is of the same structure, but has more entries and smaller time values. Using this, I updated my answer with the SQL statement that you need to modify. For readability, I did NOT include the split hours/minutes in the output, this one result the "remaining free minutes per day".

Comment: Sure, this is the right track - so in my second table there is a field called duration, the date is consistent and there is a second field for the date... so I need group the dates first from the first field, then do a calculation on the duration which looks as follows: 1899-12-30 00:05:00.000. From there I need to take just the second part, add the total up for a distinct date and then minus from the free time to get the utlisied time... wow... I think I chose a tough one today... Thankyou for your help Stefan... It is much apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 steps :

- Add the hours and minutes to the date itself
- And then Take a difference between the two dates of the same day (This would give you total time for that day)
- Then Show the date and hours separately